# File not found when application deployed on tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets

This works fine in a unit test. I get the file and can print the content. When I deploy this on a server I get a FilenotFoundExcpetion. What can be the reason for this? I am deploying on a tomcat.

```
String path = "WebContent/images/image.jpeg";

FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(path);

File image = resource.getFile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String path = "WebContent/images/image.jpeg";
```

this is a relative path, when deployed in a servlet container like tomcat it will be relative to your deployment directory or tomcat's home directory. and probably you wont have a directory named Webconent. The contents of WebContent will perhaps be inside a war perhaps.

I can think of two solutions

- Use `getRealPath` method if you have access to `request` or `ServletContext`
- Use `ClassPathResource` if you can put your file in `WEB-INF\classes`

Comment: String path = request.getRealPath("") + "/images/image.jpeg"; getRealPath is deprecated though.

Answer (score 1):

Use context path to bring location to your working project and then you can store your own path like you have mentioned images/image.jpg

```
  String path = request.getSession().getContextPath().getRealPath("/")+"images/image.jpg";
```

I guess it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

The WebContent folder is implicit, when you deploy web app onto a server.

when executing within context of web server use
String path = "/images/image.jpeg";

also

use Class.getResourceAsStream()